# Why am I missing a value when I run this loop to print each word in a string?

Tags: c++, string, loops

I am attempting to write a program that will accept an input from the user and then print each one of the words in the sentence on a separate line. The code below works except it is missing the last word in any sentence that is input. I did not include the header in this snippet. Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    string userSentence = " ";
    string permanantUserSentence = " ";
    int spaceNumber = 0;
    int wordNumber = 0;
    int characterCount = 0;
    int reverseCount = 0;
    int posLastSpace = -1;
    int posSpace = 0;

    //Begin the loop
    while(userSentence != "quit" && userSentence != "q")
    {
        //Prompt the user for their sentence
        cout << "Enter command: ";
        getline(cin, userSentence);
        permanantUserSentence = userSentence;

        //Condition to make sure values are not calculated and printed for the quit conditions
        if(userSentence != "quit" && userSentence != "q")
        {
            //Print each word in the string separately by finding where the spaces are
            int posLastSpace = -1;
            int posSpace = userSentence.find(" ", posLastSpace + 1);
            while(posSpace != -1)
            {
                cout << "expression is: " << userSentence.substr( posLastSpace+ 1, posSpace - posLastSpace - 1) << endl;
                posLastSpace = posSpace;
                //Find the next space
                posSpace = userSentence.find(" ", posLastSpace + 1);
            }
            //Clear the input buffer and start a new line before the next iteration
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you look for a space, to delimit words, but the last word does not have a space after it.

Comment: That did it. I added an if statement to the end of the nested while loop and it printed the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing the remainder of your input when you exit your while loop.

The end of the sentence generally won't have any spaces after it. So your while loop exits with some remainder (the last word and whatever follows). Therefore, you need to print the remainder of your input out to print out the word.